# Twisted upgrade - now can't access site paths

Tags: python-3.x, twisted, twisted.web

I was running on Python2.6 and Twisted 15.0.0 with this:

```
from twisted.python import usage
from twisted.web import resource, server, static
from twisted.application import internet

class Options(usage.Options):
    optParameters = [
                 ]

def makeService(options):
    # this variation works
    root_resource = static.File('/tmp')

    # this variation doesn't
    root_resource = resource.Resource()
    root_resource.putChild("here", static.File('/tmp'))

    site = server.Site(root_resource)
    web_svc = internet.TCPServer(8000, site)

    return web_svc
```

But after upgrading to Python3.7 and twisted latest (18.7.0) I can't get anything at http://localhost:8000/here

> No Such Resource
>
> No such child resource.

Can't find any twisted docs or examples that say a different way to do it.

**Additional:**

It is starting up the service fine, else I wouldn't see the above.

For reproduction purposes, the *twisted/plugins/my_plugin.py* looks like:

```
from twisted.application.service import ServiceMaker

svc = ServiceMaker("TEST_ONE",
               "svc",
               "Service",
               "tstsvc"
               )
```

And executed with:

```
twist tstsvc
```

Answer (score 1):

Mystery solved.

Of course it's Python3 here again with String handling.

```
root_resource.putChild(b"here", static.File('/tmp'))
```

Without the 'b' in front of the path, it never matched the url as typed.

Thought: Should the putChild() api throw an error if it's passed a str here? Seems bytes is always the right answer and the only thing that could match